# Any hints for dealing with snap to device pixels in WPF

Tags: wpf

Many controls in WPF has this snap to device pixels (as [explained on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx)). I just often find myself forgetting to set it and then later discover that something *sometimes* looks odd because of this.

What do people use to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SnapsToDevicePixels property is inherited through the element tree.

I always set `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` on each Window, and all the children inherit the value.

(But I don't have any suggestion for how to remember to set it on each Window.)

Answer (score 0):

SnapsToDevicePixels="True" does not trickle down into an OxyPlot grid, however...
Some of the grid lines show up double.
and OxyPlot PlotView's SnapToDevicePixels does not help either.